# Link_to Rails using Foreign and Primary Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, schema

I have two tables: Events and Images

```
Events:
id
name
date
location


Images:
id
url (where it's hosted)
caption
event_id
```

Events has many images but an image only has one event. Thus, an Event.id is connected to an Image.event_id.

I want to create a page where an image is shown with it's event's name and am struggling to do this. So far, I am able to only show the event_id on the page with the image (which is not preferred):

```
<div class="home-container">
  <% @single_image.each do |picture| %>
    <%= image_tag picture.url, :class => "body-images" %>
    <li><%= link_to picture.event_id, events_path(picture.event_id), :class => "id-link" %></li>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the name through the event association like this:

```
<div class="home-container">
  <% @single_image.each do |picture| %>
    <%= image_tag picture.url, :class => "body-images" %>
    <li><%= link_to picture.event.name, events_path(picture.event_id), :class => "id-link" %></li>
  <% end %>
</div>
```